# How to stop attributes from being pickled in Python

Tags: python, pickle

I am using gnosis.xml.pickle to convert an object of my own class to xml. The object is initialized so that:

```
self.logger = MyLogger()
```

But when I do dump the object to a string I get an exception stating that the pickler encountered an unpickleable type (thread.lock).

Is there a way to 'tag' the logger attribute so that pickler will know not to try and pickle that attribute?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can define two methods, `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`, to your class to override the default pickling behavior.

[`http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__)

`__getstate__` should return a dict of attributes that you want to pickle.

```
def __getstate__(self):
    d = dict(self.__dict__)
    del d['logger']
    return d
```

`__setstate__` should setup your object with the provided dict.

```
def __setstate__(self, d):
    self.__dict__.update(d) # I *think* this is a safe way to do it
```

Note that `__init__` won't be called when unpickling so you'll have to create your logger in `__setstate__`

Comment: thanks. please note that i am using the gnosis pickle lib, not sure if it would work the same?

Comment: I googled for the gnosis source and saw calls to getstate and setstate, so I think it will work.

Comment: I found that the `__setstate__` as written there wasn't needed since I didn't need the logger in other threads.

Answer (score 11):

This might be a better solution since it will allow an object created via `copy.deepcopy` to still have a `self.logger`:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    d = self.__dict__.copy()
    if 'logger' in d:
        d['logger'] = d['logger'].name
    return d

def __setstate__(self, d):
    if 'logger' in d:
        d['logger'] = logging.getLogger(d['logger'])
    self.__dict__.update(d)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your class can implement the special method [`__getstate__`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html?highlight=__getstate__#object.__getstate__) to return exactly what parts of an instance it wants to be pickled.

There are several possible variants on that (though `__getstate__` and its optional companion method `__setstate__` are most general) -- see the online Python doc page for `pickle`, to which I already pointed above because it's the one documenting `__getstate__`.

Comment: thanks. ideally i would like to only have to specify what i do NOT want to pickle.

Comment: @Ries, loop over all members (using inspect.getmembers, the instance's `__dict__`, whatever) and remove those you want to remove.  There is no `__donotsavetheseones_` special method, you have to implement it as `__getstate__`.